# Flutter Web: Record webcam with Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, web, camera

There is an official [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package for flutter on IOS and Android but not supported for web. Has anyone managed to record a webcam stream on Flutter Web?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow https://medium.com/@mk.pyts/how-to-access-webcam-video-stream-in-flutter-for-web-1bdc74f2e9c7  article which explains how to access the webcam in flutter web.

However, the article doesn't explain how to switch off the camera and reinitialize it.

You can take a look at my working code https://gist.github.com/CalvinGonsalves/3d01cf88a6660ca87068f17f1c99a5dd

I have experienced issues opening the webcam by running it from VScode but Android Studio works fine.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc

check for `get_user_media_sample_web.dart` in /example of flutter_webrtc package. webcam recording feature works for me.